# Remove last row from listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, checkbox

I'm using `WinForms`. I have a `ListView` with 2 columns in detail mode. I also have a button in my Form. When clicked, it adds different information to the `listview`. I placed a checkbox in my Form and i tried to delete the last row in the `listview` when it's checked, but i was having a hard time. How do i remove the last row in the `listview`?

```
        ListViewItem lvi= new ListViewItem();
        lvi.Text = "item1";
        lvi.SubItems.Add(Amount);
```

Comment: thats adding an item, not deleting one which is just `Remove` or `RemoveAt()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) method of item or [`RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx) method of items collection.

For example, you can use either of these options:

```
if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
```

```
if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Remove();
```

```
var item = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().LastOrDefault();
if (item != null)
    item.Remove();
```

Comment: Thank you! Once again you came through with a good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

this should remove the last item from the listview. Haven't had a chance to run the code - but it looks right.

```
System.Windows.Forms.ListView lv = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
lv.Items[lv.Items.Count - 1].Remove();
```